# TeXMaths-Extension for LibreOffice: No permission to use latex?

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, snap, extension, texlive

In order to use the LibreOffice extension TeXMaths, it's necessary to enter the path to the latex (and dvisvgm or dvipng) programs in the TeXMaths options. (As explained in the [installation manual](http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/install.html).)

I get the error message "not found" or "no permission" when entering this path.

On my computer, the latex program is: `/usr/bin/pdflatex`, as it was created when installing texlive.

Some other elements inside the `/usr/bin/`-directory are found by LibreOffice+TeXMaths, but unfortunately not the latex, dvisvgm or dvipng programs.

I've tried disabling AppArmor, of which I thought it might prevent permission, but this did not help.

EDIT:

Finally, found out that this is an already reported, but yet unsolved bug of the snap version of LibreOffice ([see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1747875)).

Comment: What was wrong with installing native `textlive` packages with APT?

Comment: My `texlive` (installed via `apt-get install texlive`) works usually fine, e.g. using it with `texstudio`. LibreOffice+TeXMaths don't "see" it despite that I'm sure it's there.

Comment: I had installed the snap version of LibreOffice before, and replaced it by the main version: This made the TeXMaths-extension work, hooray! :)
Being used to the snap version, I find the main version of LibreOffice a bit annoying: The design looks really different and it already crashed once... ;)

Comment: Reviewers: IMO this is about a workaround for a bug - hence not a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the snap version of LibreOffice, which I had installed before, by the main version of LibreOffice, made the TeXMaths-extension work.

At the moment (Dec '18), both versions are available in the Ubuntu-Software utility. You can tell them apart by their source and size, which are `ubuntu-bionic-updates-main` (~25 MB) and `snap store` (~500 MB).

The advantage of the snap version is that it comes all-in-one (with Writer, Impress and so on, language options, the help...) and, to me, it even looks nicer.

As I understand it, the snap version uses its own usr-path, which is on my computer:
`/snap/libreoffice/99/usr/bin`, and doesn't have permission to the main `/usr/bin`, where latex is located.

I would be happy to learn about a workaround to use the more convenient snap LibreOffice together with TeXMaths. Any ideas?